# Как сделать адаптивный slick-slider?

Tags: html, css, slick.js

Хочу сделать,чтобы при уменьшении экрана картинки в секции выстраивались по 2 штуки а на смартфонах по 1. Делал аналогично в одной из предыдущих секций,но при попытке сделать все так же,как раньше получается отстой.
На скринах представлено,как у меня было в той секции и как получается в последней.
вот как у меня получилось в секции Преимущества

```html
<section class="features">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="section-header">Преимущества работы с нами</h2>
    <div class="features-slider">
      <div class="features-block">
        <div class="features-img">
          <picture>
            <source srcset="img/features/coin.svg " type="image/">
            <img src="img/features/coin.png" alt="coin">
          </picture>
        </div>
        <div class="features-text">
          <h3>Платите по факту</h3>
          <p>Вы оплачиваете выполненные работы только после их выполнения. <br> Никаких скрытых доплат и промежуточных платежей.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="features-block">
        <div class="features-img">
          <picture>
            <source srcset="img/features/folder type=" image/>
            <img src="img/features/folder.png" alt="folder">
          </picture>
        </div>
        <div class="features-text">
          <h3>Заключаем договор</h3>
          <p>Перед началом работ заключаем договор на юридическое лицо. <br> Вы можете быть уверены, что все обязательства будут выполнены.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="features-block">
        <div class="features-img">
          <picture>
            <source srcset="img/features/clock.svg" type="image/">
            <img src="img/features/clock.png" alt="clock">
          </picture>
        </div>
        <div class="features-text">
          <h3>Точно в срок</h3>
          <p>Работаем строго по установленным срокам, которые прописаны <br> в договоре. Если не успеваем, <br> Вы платите меньше

          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="features-block">
        <div class="features-img">
          <picture>
            <source srcset="img/features/piggy-bank.svg" type="image/">
            <img src="img/features/piggy-bank.png" alt="piggy-bank">
          </picture>
        </div>
        <div class="features-text">
          <h3>Экономите на материалах</h3>
          <p>Мы являемся структурным подразделением компании поставщика строительных смесей <a class="features-link" href="#">gicema.ru</a> и даём Вам самые <br>выгодные цены.</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$('.features-slider').slick({
           infinite: true,
       slidesToShow: 4,
       slidesToScroll: 1,
       responsive: [
           
           {
             breakpoint: 991,
             settings: {
                 slidesToShow: 2,
                 slidesToScroll: 2,
                 prevArrow: '<button class="prev arrow"></button>',
                 nextArrow: '<button class="next arrow"></button>'
              }
           },
           
           {
             breakpoint: 776,
             settings: {
               slidesToShow: 1,
               slidesToScroll: 1,
               prevArrow: '<button class="prev arrow"></button>',
               nextArrow: '<button class="next arrow"></button>'
             }
           }
           
         ]
            
          });
```

А вот что я прописываю в Схема работы

```html
<section class="scheme">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="scheme-header">
      <h2>Схема работы</h2>
      <p>Работа над вашим объектом будет включать в себя следующие этапы:</p>
    </div>

    <div class="scheme-slider">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-4 scheme-block">
          <img src="img/scheme/1.png" alt="">
          <h3>Заявка</h3>
          <p>Оставляете онлайн заявку или <br>звоните +7 495 771 05 08</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-4 scheme-block scheme-two">
          <img src="img/scheme/2.png" alt="">
          <h3>Выезд специалиста</h3>
          <p>В течение 1 рабочего дня к Вам <br>приезжает специалист, который <br>выполнит замеры для точной<br> стоимости работ</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-4 scheme-block">
          <img src="img/scheme/3.png" alt="">
          <h3>Составление договора</h3>
          <p>Готовим договор и согласовываем <br>с Вами</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-4 scheme-block scheme-four">
          <img src="img/scheme/4.png" alt="">
          <h3>Начало работ</h3>
          <p>Доставляем материалы,<br>оборудование, подписываем<br> договор и начинаем работы</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-4 scheme-block">
          <img src="img/scheme/5.png" alt="">
          <h3>Завершение работ</h3>
          <p>После окончания работ Вы <br>проверяете качество и<br> подписываете акт сдачи, <br>производите оплату.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$('.scheme-slider').slick({
           infinite: true,
       slidesToShow: 4,
       slidesToScroll: 1,
       responsive: [
           
           {
             breakpoint: 991,
             settings: {
                 slidesToShow: 2,
                 slidesToScroll: 2,
                 prevArrow: '<button class="prev arrow"></button>',
                 nextArrow: '<button class="next arrow"></button>'
              }
           },
           
           {
             breakpoint: 776,
             settings: {
               slidesToShow: 1,
               slidesToScroll: 1,
               prevArrow: '<button class="prev arrow"></button>',
               nextArrow: '<button class="next arrow"></button>'
             }
           }
           
         ]
            
        });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]